# create enums options based on input info pydantic

Tags: python, enums, pydantic

I am trying to create a pydantic class which has a field with possible options,
those options should be received as input from an external api.

can it be done?

that's what I did so far:

```
class LanguageAudioEnum(str, Enum):
     pear = 'pear' # Here should be the recived options
    banana = 'banana'


class Language(BaseModel):
    language_audio: Optional[LanguageAudioEnum] = None
    language_booklet: Optional[str] = None
    language_live: Optional[str] = None

    @root_validator(pre=True)
    @classmethod
    def check_only_one_language_selected(cls, values):
        if len(values) > 1:
            raise ValueError("Select only one language option")
        elif len(values) == 0:
            raise ValueError("Select language option")
        return values
```

Another option that I came up with is to use the Literal pydantic field but still I am not sure how to enter the enums fields as input

thanx in advanced!

Oz

Comment: You can create `Enum` dynamically from dict (name-value), for example, and pass `type=str` additionally to match your definition completely. When you have this Enum, define `class Language` in that scope. I hope you're not using `mypy` or other type checkers, otherwise it will be very funny. I'd encapsulate all this into a single function and return new enum and `Language` from it, then assign them to module-level variables.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide the expected inputs and the expected behavior of the model (how will it instantiated, what is the expected value when accessing `language_audio` field).